# Loop to Count how many records in the table

Tags: sql, sas

I was wondering whether there’s a way to count the volume where the table name end with G in a loop and name it as the table name e.g output_dps_BCS_FT_G

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yZ1q.jpg)

I’m just wondering whether there is a efficient way of doing it rather than manually doing it one by one.

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: From the image, it looks like this question is about Altair / WPS.  You may want to add tags for Altair and/or SAS-WPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use SAS dictionary tables, which store metadata about all datasets in defined libraries.  You would likely want to add a WHERE clause to limit this to the libraries of interest to you.  Code like:

```
proc sql ;
  select libname,memname,nlobs from dictionary.tables
  where memname like '%G'
  ;
quit ;
```

To output the results to a SAS dataset, you can add a CREATE TABLE clause, e.g.:

```
proc sql ;
  create table G_Tables as
  select libname, memname as Filename, nlobs as Count 
  from dictionary.tables
  where memname like '%G'
  ;
quit ;

proc print data=G_Tables;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. Say if I need it in a table where the table name as filename and the counts for that table . What would be the best approach? Thanks

Comment: Add a `CREATE TABLE` clause.  I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks I got an error where it say dictionary exceed 8 character

Comment: Interesting.  From the image in your question, it looks like you're running WPS / Altair, not SAS.  It's possible that WPS has implemented the idea of dictionary tables in some other way.  But that would be surprising / disappointing, since their goal was to mimic SAS.  You might want to contact Altair support or review their documentation.

Comment: I searched the Altair docs.  It looks like they might not have implemented dictionary tables.  You could try looking in the sashelp library to see if there is a table or view there that has metadata about SAS datasets.  Perhaps run `proc contents data=sasehelp._all_;run;` and see if that returns anything useful.   In SAS, you can do `data G_tables ; set sashelp.vtable (keep=memname nlobs); where memname like '%G' ; run ;`

Comment: Yes is WPS I’m using. I did managed to get it to work using SASHELP.VTABLE

Comment: Separate question. Do you know if there a way to force the date into 0000-00-00 if blank? I try converting the dog column into character but doesn’t seem to work.currently the dob type is number length 8 format yyddmm10. Informat date9.

Comment: Dob column sorry typo

Comment: In SAS you can create a nested format where it's something like `.='0000-00-00' other=[yyddmm10.]` .  Don't know if WPS has that.